# How do I more efficiently insert footnotes into a Hexo post?

Tags: markdown, hexo, footnotes

I have been trying to insert footnotes into my Hexo posts (written in Markdown, if their markup language is relevant). I come from a background of using Jekyll to power my websites and when I used Jekyll I would add `[^n]` (where n is a positive integer, i.e., n ∈ {1,2,3,...}) in text and something like:

```
[^1]: footnote #1
[^2]: footnote #2
[^3]: footnote #3
...
```

at the end of the post where `footnote #1`, `#2`, `#3`, *etc.* are replaced with my actual footnotes. While with Hexo things seem a little more complicated. I looked for a footnote plugin at https://hexo.io/plugins/, unsuccessfully I might add, then I used Google to search for the answer and found this gist https://gist.github.com/kuanyui/d1728c2a526a615de56c. I tried to use this gist by adding it to my Hexo site's `script` folder, but this failed (for the full error details see the gist, as I commented the details there). I then tried a HTML trick I learnt by examining the generated content of my Jekyll posts that had footnotes added to them via the aforementioned method. Namely, adding:

```
<sup id="fnref:n"><a href="#fn:n" class="footnote">n</a></sup>
```

(where yet again n is a positive integer) in text where I want my footnotes to appear and:

```
<ol>
  <li id="fn:1">Footnote #1.<a href="#fnref:1" class="reversefootnote">↩</a></li>
  <li id="fn:2">Footnote #2.<a href="#fnref:2" class="reversefootnote">↩</a></li>
  <li id="fn:3">Footnote #3.<a href="#fnref:3" class="reversefootnote">↩</a></li>
  ...
</ol>
```

to the end of the post. The problem is that this method, while effective, is also tedious (i.e., per footnote it requires a lot more typing than I would like), so I tried creating this ejs template (which corresponds to the in-text footnotes), which I placed in my `layouts` folder under the name `footnotes.ejs`:

```
<sup id ="fnref:<%= n %>"><a href="#fn:<%= n %>"><%= n %></a></sup>
```

and inserting this into my posts with:

```
<%- include('layouts/footnotes', {n:1}); %>
```

but this too failed (by failed I mean when I generated my hexo site this in-text citation was left completely unformatted).

So I am here to ask for a more efficient way to insert footnotes into Hexo posts. Namely one that requires as little typing, per footnote, as possible.

Comment: Have you tried the [hexo-renderer-marked](https://github.com/hexojs/hexo-renderer-marked) plugin? That plugin uses [Marked](https://github.com/chjj/marked) for parsing Markdown and Marked supports footnotes via the `gfm` (GitHub Flavored Markdown) option.

Comment: There is also the [hexo-renderer-markdown-it](https://github.com/celsomiranda/hexo-renderer-markdown-it) plugin, which uses the [Markdown-It](https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) Markdown parser and also supports footnotes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just created a hexo-plugin to support markdown footnotes :

- [Github repository](https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro/hexo-footnotes)
- [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hexo-footnotes)

So, you just have to install the package with

```
npm install hexo-footnotes --save
```

If Hexo detect automatically all plugins, that's all.

If that is not the case, register the plugin in your `_config.yml` file :

```
plugins:
  - hexo-footnotes
```

**Here is the syntax** :

```md
basic footnote[^1]
here is an inline footnote[^2](inline footnote)
and another one[^3]
and another one[^4]

[^1]: basic footnote content
[^3]: paragraph
footnote
content
[^4]: footnote content with some [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)
```

**Here is the result** :

[image: footnotes]